# jquery scaling images

Tags: jquery, image, scale

Is there a way to actually scale and not just resize images with jquery. I have built a lightbox but some of the images are big so needs to scale them down to fit the available browser space.

I am not that concened about file size but quality is an issue so so not just want to use css or the width and height attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: No, there isn't.

However, most current browsers implement CSS properties (as listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Image-rendering#Browser_Compatibility)) to specify the algorithm used to scale images.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is set `max-height` and `max-width` to the desired amount, that way the aspect ratio will be kept, but the filesize will be the same though.